# How to specify the type of text in UITextField

Tags: swift, regexkitlite

I'm trying to determine whether or not a user is entering a proper email address into a UITextField . I'm using this code but am getting the following error message.

```
 func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let range = testStr.rangeOfString(emailRegEx, options:.RegularExpressionSearch) // I'm getting the error message here.
    let result = range != nil ? true : false
    return result
}
@IBAction func logIn(sender: AnyObject) {
    let validLogin = isValidEmail(testStr: field.text!)
    if validLogin {
        print("User entered valid input")
    } else {
        print("Invalid email address")
    }
}
```

This is the error message I'm getting: "Value of type 'String' has no member 'rangeOfString'"

I think this is because I don't have RegExKitLite installed but I'm not 100% sure. Even so, I tried installing the kit but I couldn't figure out how. I downloaded the file but I can't figure out how to add it in Xcode.

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? It looks like you are still using Swift 2 for some reason.

Comment: You should use home-brew and cocoaPods to add the RegExKitLite to your project. You need to convert your string to NSString() to use rangeOfString

Comment: @rmaddy Version 9.2. It should be 3?

Comment: @Jake How would I go about doing this? Sorry, I'm really new to this.

Comment: You can change the function parameters to (testStr: NSString) or add `as! NSString` at the end of the `let range` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swift 3 or later, the lines:

```
let range = testStr.rangeOfString(emailRegEx, options:.RegularExpressionSearch)
let result = range != nil ? true : false
return result
```

needs to be:

```
let range = testStr.range(of: emailRegEx, options: [ .regularExpression ])
return range != nil
```

None of this needs a third party library.

You probably also want to make sure the whole string matches so you should add `^` to the start of the regular expression and add `$` to the end.

Comment: I'm getting the following error message: Value of type 'Range<String.Index>?' has no member 'location'

Comment: @MatthewKaplan Fixed.